# How to show image over navbar using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to implement a navbar using HTML and CSS, where I want to place a half portion of an image over the navbar as similar to the below image:  [image]

So what I get so far is:
[image]

Half portion of the image goes below the navbar rather than showing over the navbar.

I have added `z-index: 1` for navbar and set `z-index: 100` for the image, but it does not work!

Here is the `CSS` for Navbar:

```
.mynmenu {
  width: auto !important;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative !important;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left:0px;
  width: auto;
  height: 60px;
 }
```

Here is the `CSS` for Image:

```
.circle_image img {
width: 80px !important;
height: 80px !important;
position: absolute;
z-index: 100;
left: 20% !important;
top: -20px !important;
border-right: 8px solid #ffffff !important;
border-bottom: 8px solid #ffffff !important;
border-top: 8px solid #cccccc !important;
border-left: 8px solid #cccccc !important;
}
```

HTML code as follows:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue??

- Thanks

Comment: Please supply your code or we cant help

Comment: Code included. Now check

Comment: Can you supply the html as well...? Just put the whole thing in a snip.

Comment: @Laif Now check

Comment: @Shimul My guy, I do not want a screenshot of your code. If you want us to put in the work to answer your question, please put in your entire code chunk for us to mess with. I'm not going to attempt to eyeball this issue or copy your code directly from the image.

Comment: @Shimul +1 for "My guy" OP if you are asking for help please make it as easy to help you as possible. pasting a screenshot means i have to retype all of your code to test on my machine. update your question with the actual code, not a picture, when you get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you have started, but here can be a solution with bootstrap:

.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-5 border-bottom border-danger pr-2 align-middle">
    <ul class="d-inline-block">
      <li class="p-2">Self Storage</li>
      <li class="p-2">Moving Magazine</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-2 p-3 your-image rounded-circle align-middle"></div>

  <div class="col-5 border-bottom border-danger pl-2 align-middle"></div>
</div>
```

.css

```
.your-image {
  background: url("…");
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 3rem;
}
```